# Send a message via XMPPFramework for iOS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xmppframework

How do I send a message through the XMPPFramework for objc and ios?

Its really bugging me now. I need to build a custom method with some custom XML and send it to a specific JID.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: HI, can u please guide me on how to add XMPPFramework, i googled but the links gives 404 error.. some XMPPFrameworks i downloaded like iPhoneXMPP but its gives errors ..Please Guide me @Thomas Clayson

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:textvalue];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
[message addChild:body];

[[self xmppStream] sendElement:message];
```

try this

Comment: Please check this question. Im doing what you suggest, with no result: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096649/xmppframework-message-not-sent

Comment: HI, can u please guide me on how to add XMPPFramework, i googled but the links gives 404 error.. some XMPPFrameworks i downloaded like iPhoneXMPP but its gives errors ..Please Guide me  @harshalb