# XMPPFramework message not sent

Tags: iphone, ios, xmppframework

I receive messages from a Google Talk account, they are shown in the Table View in the Ios emulator, but when i send it, it is not shown in the Google Talk client (in another computer). This is the code:

```
-(IBAction)sendchat:(id)sender
{
General *general = [General sharedManager];//It is a singleton class used to store some values that need to be accesible in the whole application.


NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
text=[mensaje text];
NSLog(@"Texto en el body: %@", text);
[body setStringValue:text];
NSArray *dest=[general.firstfrom componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];//in firstfrom is stored the account from wich we receive the first message. This app cannot start a conversation itself, must only answer

NSLog(@"Destination trimmed: %@", [dest objectAtIndex:0]);//Here, the destination account shows correctly (without the /xxxx stuff, just name@gmail.com)
XMPPMessage *mens=[[XMPPMessage alloc]init];
[mens addAttributeWithName:@"body" stringValue:text];
[mens addAttributeWithName:@"sender" stringValue:general.userlogin];
NSLog(@"text vale: %@", text);
NSXMLElement *messagetosend = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[messagetosend addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[messagetosend addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[dest objectAtIndex:0]];
[messagetosend addChild:body];
NSLog(@"We are sending to: %@", [dest objectAtIndex:0]);
[self.xmppStream sendElement:messagetosend];

[self xmppStream:xmppStream didReceiveMessage:mens];//manage the sent message as it was received, to show it in the Table View
self.mensaje.text=@"";
}
```

As I say, messages are received perfectly, but I cannot send. Ive seen plenty of examples of how to send, and they are like my code. If i debug sender it is shown ok (namesender@gmail.com), and the "to" attribute is ok too (namereceiver@gmail.com). The xmppStrem is set correctly (as far as i know):

```
xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

In ViewDidLoad method.

Any help? Thank you.

---EDIT---

I forgot to say, both accounts know each others and in the Google Talk client, the presence is sent.

Comment: you should check the jid values..i dont exactly remember but i think they differ from the emailID.

Comment: HI, can u please guide me on how to add XMPPFramework, i googled but the links gives 404 error.. some XMPPFrameworks i downloaded like iPhoneXMPP but its gives errors ..Please Guide me @Fustigador

Comment: Hi Babul, this is the page where i found the info: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS  Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I had two classes receiving messages, because Class A must receive a message to trigger the pushing of the view of the class B (this app is unable to start a chat conversation by itself). So, i set two xmppStream, one for every class. I put an xmppStream in my General class, make both classes take that xmppStream, and it now sends messages.

Comment: @Fustigador i am facing same problem when i send message send element method is not calling.but in login time it is calling perfectly..please help me

Comment: I would like to help you, but its been a lot of time since I used xmppFramework ..